# Asp.net Forms Authentication & IIS Default Document causes an extra execution page load of default document which had set in IIS default doc

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

Scenario :

1. I am having default document set up in IIS to Home.aspx.
2. Forms authentication's default URL in Web.config is Default.aspx.
3. For ex., Cliking any link in Default.aspx is navigating to page X.
4. Now Home.aspx's Load event is getting executing.

Step #4 (Executing Home pages load event) is not correct, But I dont know how home.aspx is related with Default.aspx page's Redirect event?

Problem - Always Home.aspx page 's Load event is getting executing.

Could you please help me on this?

Regards,

Karthik

Answer (score 1):

The code behind class of your Default.aspx is probably pointing to your homepage class.

Check your page declarations in Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="**Default.aspx.cs**" Inherits="YourNamespace.Default"
    MasterPageFile="~/Masters/YourMaster.master"  %>
```